# clang (even with no args) takes 0.7 seconds to execute

Tags: macos, performance, clang

```
$ time nonexistent-command
zsh: command not found: nonexistent-command
nonexistent-command  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.425 total
$ time clang
clang: error: no input files
clang  0.01s user 0.68s system 40% cpu 1.682 total
```

Since clang is invoked every time `./configure` tries a C/C++ snippet, running configure on a project takes something like 5-10 *minutes*.

```
$ time ./configure
[...]
./configure  29.65s user 542.02s system 96% cpu 9:50.57 total
```

I've managed to track this down to a call to `fparseln` inside the clang binary, but that's it.

Instruments SS:

[image: instruments view]

Corresponding assembler inside clang:

[image: assembler]

This issue is appearing for me and for my coworkers, but not for others I've asked. It happened both on High Sierra and on Catalina (I tried upgrading, but that did not fix it).

Everyone on a mac at my office has this issue, so it may be something the IT grunts installed, but no idea what or how to find it. Ideas on how to proceed and/or fix?

Comment: Antivirus software? It's a good way to cripple a machine and reading streams from files or devices could well be caught by it and being mishandled.

Comment: Right on. I honestly thought I had turned it off but even with the app turned off there was an *unkillable* (even for root) process, and an untouchable (even for root) directory in /Lib../App..Supp/.

Comment: Yeah, in many cases "turning it off" just disables the active pause while scanning a file against their database, all the low-level hooks and pass-through of data still goes through their program and can cause a problem. Glad you found the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this *only* affected people inside my office, I suspected it was some software that the company installed. Turns out I was right:

**Cylance was causing this issue.**